# css padding between dynamically generated divs

Tags: html, css

I have a js fiddle where i want a padding between two divs, i have placed a css padding rule on the div that requires padding but it is not being applied:

http://jsfiddle.net/Cnr2V/
css:

```
.gap {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 15%;
        height: 300px;
        float: left;
        background-image: url("/images/forward_enabled_hover.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
    }

    .feature-addons {
        background-color: #303030;
        width: 100%;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 15px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .feature-container {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 40%;
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .feature-item {
        padding: 5px;
        height: 50px;
        display: block;
    }

    .feature-options {
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        background-image: url("/images/plus.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center right;
    }

    .radio-button {
        display: none;
    }
```

html:

```
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_Content_Wraper_ctl01_UpdatePanel_Features">
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_Content_Wraper_ctl01_Panel_FeatureOptions">
    <div class="call-features-table">
        <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_Content_Wraper_ctl01_Panel_SelectFeatures" class="feature-container">
            <div class="feature-addons">Feature add-ons</div>
            <label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_Content_Wraper_ctl01_RadioButton_Item" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_Content_Wraper_ctl01_Label_FeatureItem">
                <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_Content_Wraper_ctl01_Panel_FeatureItem" class="feature-item">
                    <div class="feature-options">
                         <h4>Title</h4>

                        <p>lorum ipsum</p>
                        <p>lorum ipsum</p> <span class="radio-button"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_Content_Wraper_ctl01_RadioButton_Item" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder_Content_Wraper$ctl01$RadioButton_Item" value="RadioButton_Item" /></span>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </label>
            <label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_Content_Wraper_ctl01_RadioButton_Item" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_Content_Wraper_ctl01_Label1">
                <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_Content_Wraper_ctl01_Panel1" class="feature-item">
                    <div class="feature-options">
                         <h4>Title</h4>

                        <p>lorum ipsum</p> <span class="radio-button"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_Content_Wraper_ctl01_RadioButton1" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder_Content_Wraper$ctl01$RadioButton1" value="RadioButton1" /></span>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="gap"></div>
        <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_Content_Wraper_ctl01_Panel_SelectedFeatures" class="feature-container"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i create the padding required between two **feature-item** divs?

Comment: the second feature container is empty

Comment: If you want space between elements you use `margin` not `padding`

Comment: sorry i meant feature-item div. edited question

Comment: You're supposed to post just the relevant code, trimmed down to the minimum useful to illustrate the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined height for `feature-item` which is not allowing space between the divs. Try removing the height or specify a higher value.

Answer (score 1):

Remove height from feature-item div.

```
.feature-item {
    padding: 5px;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are applying feature-item class to a div which is already a block element, Removing height will solve your query, but removing extra css will also improve your code quality. So you just need to write :-

```
.feature-item {
    padding: 5px;
}
```